# Ignite UI export large dataset halts the page

Tags: javascript, html, ignite-ui

The version I'm using is 15.2. Previously I have been having no problems downloading a small dataset into Excel. However, for the current page, the data set is slightly larger than usual (280 rows x 14 columns). Every time I click the export button the page will halt (no Excel is generated after waiting for a min+). Does anyone have similar experience like this before and how to work around it?

Here's a snippet of the export function

```
$('#exportButton')
        .on({
            click: function() {
                var fileName = getExportFileNameForSingleDate("NAV_Comparison");

                $.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid($("#grid"),
                    {
                        fileName: fileName,
                        tableStyle: 'tableStyleLight13'
                    },
                    {
                        exportStarting: function(e, args) {
                            showExportingIndicator(args.grid, exportingIndicator);
                        },
                        success: function() {
                            hideExportingIndicator(exportingIndicator);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });

function showExportingIndicator(grid, exportingIndicator) {
    exportingIndicator.css({
            "width": grid.outerWidth(),
            "height": grid.outerHeight()
        })
        .html('<span class="exporting-text">Processing...</span>');
    exportingIndicator.addClass("exporting-indicator");

    grid.append(exportingIndicator);
}

function hideExportingIndicator(exportingIndicator) {
    exportingIndicator.remove();
}
```

Comment: Do you have some specifics in your cell values? There's an example(https://www.igniteui.com/grid/export-feature-rich-grid) with a grid with more than 500 rows and 6 columns and the exporting is pretty fast.

Comment: @dkamburov Do you mean by special characters? No I don't have any special characters it's just a mix of plain text and numbers. Have you tried anything successful with more than 2000 rows before?

Comment: You said you're having dataset with 280 rows. I'll give it a try with more records. But if you have bigger data set it will require more time to be exported, have you considered using paging and exporting pages with useful data?

Comment: Here's an example(http://jsfiddle.net/dkamburov/8unab211/) with 2500+ records. It is working fine in my opinion.

Comment: As I commented earlier, both paging and grid virtualization are good options in terms of performance. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you upgraded your product to a higher version ? Supporting hierarchical data exporting was introduced in 16.1 and this definitely slowed down exporting,though in latest versions this performance issue was handled and as you can see in this example (http://jsfiddle.net/8unab211/1/)exporting 2500 records x 12 columns seems pretty fine. I can have a further look if you specify the exact version used and provide a sample chunk of your data:

```
        $.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid($("#grid1"), {
            fileName: "igGrid",
            gridFeatureOptions: {
                paging: "allRows",
            },
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think paging is definitely a good way to handling large dataset. However, I recently found out that grid virtualization also solve the problem. I'll mark your answer as solved.